# Cannot install SharePoint on Windows Server 2008 Standard

Tags: sharepoint-2007, windows-server-2008

I am attempting to install SharePoint 2007 (WSS 3.0) on a MS Windows Server 2008 SP2 box.  Immediately after extracting the files the install fails with the error: "The installation of this package failed."  I filename was SharePoint.exe and it is the version with SP2 already in it (file size ~ 106MB).

How do I install SharePoint on Windows Server 2008 Standard (not R2)?

EDIT:  Adding:
I extracted the files by running from the command line with "/extract:[path] in the command line, but when I run setup.exe from the extracted files I get the error "The language of this installation package is not supported by your system."  Perhaps this error is why the installation is failing?  Searching for this error message reveals that this error is associated mostly with problems with Office.  Any ideas?

Comment: Do you get any other error, like an error number or code?

Comment: Nope!  The error message is in an alert box / dialog with "Microsoft Windows SharePoint Services" in the title bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded the file for the 4th time this afternoon and it finally worked.  I assume the download got corrupted somehow.